# Issues using Mail PEAR with php on a server

Tags: php, email, pear

I would like to use PEAR to be able to send smtp emails.
I know that PEAR is installed on my server and the include_path are well defined.
But the: `require_once 'Mail.php';` returns error:

> Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/[username]/php')
>   in /home/[username]/public_html/email_test.php

But the code below works fine:

```
require_once 'System.php';
if(class_exists('System')===true) {
   echo 'PEAR is installed!';
} else {
   echo 'PEAR is not installed :(';
}
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally PEAR packages get installed in a directory that is added by PEAR to the include path, but I don't see any specific PEAR path here. See https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.config.php

Comment: The path to your file could be wrong.